# convert arabic charset to readable character for browser

Tags: php, mysql

I use below function to convert my charset to readable arabic for PHP, When I create file/folder with arabic characters it works fine.

```
$path = iconv('UTF-8', "windows-1256//IGNORE", $path);
```

I faced a problem when I save this into a table that I set charset cp1265. As you can see `attached_files` or `picture` are columns for files.

[image]

When I fetch rows from database and echo files. just shows ????? for arabic characters. even in spite of converting with below code.

```
$path = iconv("windows-1256",'UTF-8', $path);
```